# Google Fusion Table: Unauthorized with api key

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create and query a fusion table. So what I did:

1. I created a new fusion table in google drive
2. Created a new api key
3. Set the fusion table to public (using share button)

Now I'm using Advanced REST client executing this request:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables?key=[myapikey]

But I keep getting 401: Unauthorized

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

The docs say that this should work, but I keep getting this message. Any hint?

p.s.: The reason why I use an api key only is simply because I created a batch which sends the request, the data is public and there is no user authentication required.

Comment: Update 1: It seems in order to work with fusion tables you need to use oAuth or service accounts, it doesnt work with just api keys. You can actually ommit them.

Update 2: Getting a service account which has access to my fusion table still seems to be a hard challenge